# How to disable ActiveRecord query caching that Octopus enforces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, octopus

I'm using Octopus (latest version) with Rails (latest version) and ActiveAdmin on 2 DBs, one master for writes and one slave for reads. The problem now is, when we add any new DB entry, it is being written to the DB, but it is not being displayed on the index page because the query was cached before we create the new records!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Makara gem instead and it is working fine.